# Problems with map as array

Tags: c++, std

Good day!

I'm making nondeterministic finite automata with c++. I want to make a transition table. As you know, it should return a set of states. For example, table[state][symbol] should return {q0,q1, etc..}.

I'm using std::map and std::set for this. I found this useful example : [how to use stl::map as two dimension array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393243/how-to-use-stlmap-as-two-dimension-array)

So, i wrote some code:

```
std::map <set<state>, std::map<state,char> > transitionTable;
```

But when i'm trying to acsess the table like

`set<state> result = transitionTable[oldState][symbol];`

I get an error:

```
C:\NFA2\main.cpp||In function 'std::set<state, std::less<state>, std::allocator<state> > delta(state, char)':|
C:\NFA2\main.cpp|17|error: no match for 'operator[]' in 'transitionTable[oldState]'|
```

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't edit your questions in a way that invalidates all given answers. You can instead add additional info if you have more problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you want (`typedef`s for readability):

```
typedef std::set<state> StateSet;
typedef std::map<char, StateSet> SymbolToStatesMap;
typedef std::map<state, SymbolToStatesMap> TransitionTable;

TransitionTable transitionTable;
```

Keep in mind that the first type argument to `map` is the key type, so if you want an access like this:

```
A a;
B b;
C c = myMap[a][b];
```

the map type should be:

```
std::map<A, std::map<B, C> >
```

---

To actually be able to use custom types as a key in a map, they have to implement `operator<`:

```
class state {
    // ...
public:
    bool operator<(const state& rhs) const {
        // ... custom stuff here
    }
```

Alternatively you can pass a custom comparer to `map`.

Comment: Thanks. But now there is anoter error after this changes:`c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|230|error: no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'|`

Comment: @Skyrocker: I guess `state` is a custom type and you don't have `operator<` implemented for it?

Comment: Yes, it is my type, but i don't need any comparsion from it. But state is a struct with only one `string` field, so may be i can use string instead of my `struct state`.

Comment: I've used `string` instead `state` and it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sky: See the edit for how to use custom types as key in a map.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `oldState` is a set. If that is the case, `transitionTable[oldState]` returns you a map and `transitionTable[oldState][symbol]` is invalid if symbol is not a set and hence error.

Comment: No, oldState is one state, not a set.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::map <set<state>, std::map<state,char> > transitionTable;
```

You have a **set** as key in the map, not a state.

Answer (score 0):

What are the types of `oldState` and `symbol`?

From what I understand of your problem, I suspect that the type
of `transitionTable` should be:

```
std::map<std::set<state>, std::map<char,std::set<state> > transitionTable;
```

At least, this would give the mapping: `(set_of_states, char) ->
set_of_states`, if used as in your example, where `oldState` is
a set of states, and `symbol` is a `char`.