# How to write 3d mapping in C++?

Tags: c++, mapping

Can you please tell me how I can write multidimensional map. For two dimensional map, I did the following:

```
map<string, int> Employees
Employees[“person1”] = 200;
```

I was trying to use something similar to following for 3d mapping.

```
map<string, string, int> Employees;
Employees[“person1”, “age”] = 200;
```

Can you please tell me the correct way to do this?

and Is there a way I can initialize all the map elements to be 0 ? Just like on a array we can say `int array[10]={0};`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create map of maps like that.

```
map<string, map<string, int> > employees;
employees["person1"]["age"] = 200;
```

Comment: Is there a way I can initialize all the map function to be 0 ? Just like on a array we can say `int array[10]={0};`

Comment: The call to map[key] initializes the object with the type default constructor. For integer this is exactly zero. This means that for any two randomly chosen keys `emplyees["foo"]["bar"] == 0` will return true.

Comment: Ok, I should have tried it out first. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `pair` class of the `utility` library to combine two objects:

```
map<pair<string, string>, int> Employees;
Employees[make_pair("person1", "age")] = 200;
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of nested map, you can use tuple as keys; (this is a c++11 code, you could do the same with `boost::tuple` as well).

```
#include<map>
#include<tuple>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
map<tuple<string,string>,int> m;
int main(){
    m[make_tuple("person1","age")]=33;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing here is not 3D mapping but 2D mapping, [how to use stl::map as two dimension array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393243/how-to-use-stlmap-as-two-dimension-array)

Correct 3D mapping will be like

```
map<string, map<string, map<int, string> > > Employees;
Employees[“person1”][“age”][20] = "26/10/2014";
```