# How to implement a non contiguous dynamic Matrix in C++ like php?

Tags: php, c++, matrix, data-structures

In php you can create a matrix like `$mat1 = array();` without knowing the size of the array and add elements in non sequential index like first `$mat1[1][3] = x` then `$mat1[2][0] = y` and so on. How can this be implemented in C++? 
Also same thing for a 1D array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have in PHP is an *associative array*; it's called `std::map<>` in C++. If you want an int -> int -> string map, you need:

```
std::map< int, std::map< int, std::string > > mat1;
```

Note that this does not preserve the order which the keys are inserted.

If you don't know the *number of* dimensions in advance, you might create a recursive data structure where each value is either of a value_type or a map.

Comment: It is actually more technically correct to say that in PHP the implementation of an array is an ordered hashmap (_not really an array as in a vector_). So similar to C++ map, but with order of insertion preserved regardless of the key. In C++ a `map` sorts elements by key, which is not the case in PHP.

Comment: @Sherif: note that an ordered hashmap is an associative array :). That said, the second and third sentence is important, so I've edited the answer. (btw. is there a simple, clean, pragmatic way to represent an ordered associative container in C++ w/o keeping two containers or rolling your own?)

Comment: Not necessarily, no. __Associative array__ is somewhat dubious. In PHP arrays share some characteristics of a vector/list and _some_ characteristics of a hashmap. For example, in PHP you are not required to supply a key, but keys also have no effect on the ordering of elements, access, or even memory allocation. This is also why PHP's implementation of the array is made up of 3 levels of indirection. The `hashtable`, the `bucket`, and the doubly linked list of `bucket`s. This addresses your last question (_without that 3rd level you get more resizing of the hash due to collision_).

Comment: @Sherif: got your point. So you need a list/vector and an unordered_map (one having iterators to the other, other having elements) to exactly mimic it in C++, it doesn't get simpler than that. Also, since PHP is (well, was, some time ago) dynamically typed, that might be simulated using `boost::any<>`.

Comment: @lorro Thanks! I had thought about this but wasn't sure. And I tried checking boost but at first it seemed to be an overkill, although the documentation is not very clear to me. I will test this method and get back if I need anything else.

Answer (score 2):

[From the PHP manual](http://php.net/language.types.array)

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

So check here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/
and : [how to use stl::map as two dimension array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393243/how-to-use-stlmap-as-two-dimension-array)